# are there two class names in this line?

Tags: javascript

```
var createSongRow = function(songNumber, songName, songLength) {
var template =
    '<tr class="album-view-song-item">'
+ '  <td class="song-item-number" data-song-number="' + songNumber + '">' + songNumber + '</td>'
+ '   <td class="song-item-title">' + songName + '</td>'
+ '   <td class="song-item-duration">' + songLength + '</td>'
+ '</tr>'
;
return template;
};
```

in the line `<td class="song-item-number" data-song-number="' + songNumber + '">' + songNumber + '</td>'` is data-song-number another class id?

Answer (score 1):

No. In

```
<td class="song-item-number" data-song-number="' + songNumber + '">' + songNumber + '</td>'`
```

we say

- `td` is an element
- the `td` element has two *attributes*

  - attribute `class` has value `"song-item-number"`
  - attribute `data-song-number` has value whatever the value of the `songNumber` variable is
- the *content* of the `td` element is also the value of the `songNumber` variable.

The term "className" you asked about sometimes shows up in client-side JavaScript programming. It refers to the `class` attribute, and is only called `className` because calling it `class` might conflict with a reserved word in a host programming language. If you had said

```
<td class="a b">...</td>
```

then you could speak of the `td` element as having two classes (for CSS targeting perhaps), but we wouldn't say it has two "class names." At any rate, that certainly is not what is going on in your example; your `td` element has only one class.

Answer (score 0):

`data-song-number` is not a class.

[**data**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) is an attribute which allow to store extra information>It basically forms a type of information related to the element.

Any text can be attached to `data-` which gives a meaningful name about the type of the information associated with the element.

For this example

```
<div data-name = 'John' id = "someDiv></div>
var _name= document.getElementById("someDiv");
_name.getAttribute("data-name"); // will get the current value of data-name
_name.setAttribute("data-name",'Player'); // will set he new value
```